# OpenCV in macbook and raspberry pi

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi2, macos-high-sierra

I wrote this code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640, 480))

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    out.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But my the code is not capturing any videos. The file output.avi is 6kb is size no matter how long the recording goes.

The same code was implemented in raspberry pi with picamera. The video in the window is extremely slow and also the captured file shows only 1 frame for the whole time of video.

I'm using OpenCV 3.1.

Comment: Is 'XVID' the correct codec? If not, could that be why you are not getting a video file captured?

Comment: I tried with many other codecs. Nothing works.